# jQuery mobile button act

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

Picture :http://u1312.hizliresim.com/1j/y/w0yr4.png

Hi everyone, I have a form page. When I give the button type="submit" it is automatically re-size. As you can see second button. But others button's width is long. :/ It is the same code, the only difference is `type="submit"`

First Button :

```
<div data-role="fieldcontain" class="no-field-separator">
  <a href="#popupMenu" data-rel="popup" data-mini="true" data-role="button" data-transition="slideup" data-icon="star" data-theme="e">Resim Çek</a>
</div>
```

Second Button:

```
<div data-role="fieldcontain" class="no-field-separator">
  <button id="submitForm" class="btnLogin" data-iconpos="left " type="submit" data-theme="a" data-mini="true">Gönder</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Do you have any CSS with this code?

Answer (score 0):

change the second button to `<input type="submit"/>` and overwrite the default css properties.

**Try this code:**

**First Button:**

```
<div data-role="fieldcontain" class="no-field-separator">
  <a href="#popupMenu" data-rel="popup" data-mini="true" data-role="button" data-transition="slideup" data-icon="star" data-theme="e">Resim Çek</a>
</div>
```

**Second Button:**

```
<div data-role="fieldcontain" class="no-field-separator">
    <input id="submitForm" class="btnLogin" data-iconpos="left " type="submit" data-theme="a" data-mini="true" value="Gönder"/>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.ui-btn {
    margin: 0.5em 0 !important;   /* used to be margin: 0.5em 5px; */
    width:100% !important;
}
```

HERE IS A WORKING [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/s62sM/)

Comment: `.ui-field-contain .ui-btn.ui-submit {
    width: 100%;
}` to override submit button inside field contain **only**. http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/s62sM/1/